# perform a replace only in the first 3 characters

Tags: php

In php, how can I perform a replace only in the first 3 characters in a string?

So:

```
$str = /pr/printers

Replace 'pr' with 'or'. So its -> /or/printers.
```

What's happening to me is, the pr in the printer is being replaced as well. So I'm ending up with /or/orinters. How can this be done?

Comment: Is the part that you want to replace always enclosed in slashes? `/` and is the text always `pr` that you want to replace?

Comment: `$str = /pr/printers` - is not valid php!

Comment: @Jack well it is. It will just have ERRORS.

Comment: @Neal There's a name for things that don't compile, it's called rubbish.

Comment: @Jack tomato tomato. (wow that sounded better in my head)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$new = str_replace('/pr/', '/or/', '/pr/printers');

You can also use regular expressions like this:
http://www.laprbass.com/RAY_temp_norman.php

```
<?php // RAY_temp_norman.php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$rgx 
= '#'    // REGEX  DELIMITER
. '^'    // START OF STRING
. '/pr'  // PATTERN TO MATCH
. '#'    // REGEX DELIMITER
. 'i'    // OPTIONAL- CASE-INSENSITIVE
;

$str = '/pr/printers';
$rep = '/or';

$new = preg_replace($rgx, $rep, $str);
var_dump($new);
```

Comment: You can also use regular expressions.  The caret ^ can be used to designate the start of a string.

Comment: In the end, we decided to use preg_replace with the 1 at the end. Works for now.

Answer (score 4):

Just me or most of the answers fail to address the real question?  What if the rest of the string gets a match.  He just wants the first 3 charecters to be in play.  I think I see one preg comment mentioning use of `^` which also makes sense.

```
$originalStr = '/pr/printers';
$prefix = substr($originalStr, 0, 3);
$newStr = str_replace("/pr","/or", $prefix) . substr($originalStr, 3);
echo $newStr;
```

Comment: You didn't see Clement's answer?

Comment: He added his after mine, just had to one up me getting it on fewer lines :)

Comment: The times on your answers suggests otherwise though.

Comment: Well he certainly got my up-vote.  Should the world end today I fell this question will have been thoroughly answered.

Answer (score 2):

Using `str_replace()`:

```
$str = '/pr/printers';
$str = str_replace("/pr/","/or/",$str);
echo $str;
```

Using `preg_replace()` (the 4th parameter is limit which i set to 1)"

```
$str = '/pr/printers';
$str = preg_replace("/pr/","or",$str,1);
echo $str;
```

Comment: In this case, str_replace is a better choice. Regular expressions have a bit more overhead, but have much more power than simple string replacements.

Comment: How do either of these "replace only in the first 3 characters in a string"?

Comment: @ficuscr, The boundaries in `str_replace()` and the last parameter to `preg_replace` *effectively* "replace only in the first 3 characters in a string".

Comment: @JasonMcCreary No, *effectively* they work only for the given example, not in a general case.

Comment: @Yoshi, but of course :). If we're going to get technical. The question title and the example conflict. Hence the specific answers.

Comment: “Marge, I agree with you — in theory. In theory, communism works. In theory.” — Homer Simpson

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = '/pr/printers';

$newStr = str_replace('pr', 'or', mb_substr($str, 0, 3)) . mb_substr($str, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using regular expressions, a scary beast but once mastered very powerful if you are going to do more general text manipulations:

http://webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php